# Shuffling an array of strings

Tags: android, random, arrays

I have set up a technique for shuffling Strings.

```
int Random = (int) (Math.random() *4);
```

I am not sure how I can get this to work with my String Array. I would like to randomise all the Strings I have in the array and the output result to still be an Array but with all the String in random order.

In all the questions I have looked at related to doing this, people just use the int when setting the text of their text view.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    public static final String[] imageThumbUrlsRandom = new String[] {


    "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-TzF_LwrCnRM/URqu0RddPOI/AAAAAAAAAbs/gaj2dLiuX0s/s160-c/Lone%252520Pine%252520Sunset.jpg",
    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-4HdpJ4_DXU4/URqu046dJ9I/AAAAAAAAAbs/eBOodtk2_uk/s160-c/Lonely%252520Rock.jpg",
    "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-erbF--z-W4s/URqu1ajSLkI/AAAAAAAAAbs/xjDCDO1INzM/s160-c/Longue%252520Vue.jpg",
    "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-0CXJRdJaqvc/URqu1opNZNI/AAAAAAAAAbs/PFB2oPUU7Lk/s160-c/Look%252520Me%252520in%252520the%252520Eye.jpg",
    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-D_5lNxnDN6g/URqu2Tk7HVI/AAAAAAAAAbs/p0ddca9W__Y/s160-c/Lost%252520in%252520a%252520Field.jpg",
    "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-flsqwMrIk2Q/URqu24PcmjI/AAAAAAAAAbs/5ocIH85XofM/s160-c/Marshall%252520Beach%252520Sunset.jpg",
    "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Y4lgryEVTmU/URqu28kG3gI/AAAAAAAAAbs/OjXpekqtbJ4/s160-c/Mono%252520Lake%252520Blue.jpg",
    "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-AaHAJPmcGYA/URqu3PIldHI/AAAAAAAAAbs/lcTqk1SIcRs/s160-c/Monument%252520Valley%252520Overlook.jpg",
    "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-vKxfdQ83dQA/URqu31Yq_BI/AAAAAAAAAbs/OUoGk_2AyfM/s160-c/Moving%252520Rock.jpg",
    "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-CG62QiPpWXg/URqu4ia4vRI/AAAAAAAAAbs/0YOdqLAlcAc/s160-c/Napali%252520Coast.jpg",
    "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-wdGrP5PMmJQ/URqu5PZvn7I/AAAAAAAAAbs/m0abEcdPXe4/s160-c/One%252520Wheel.jpg",
    "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-6WS5DoCGuOA/URqu5qx1UgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/giMw2ixPvrY/s160-c/Open%252520Sky.jpg",
    "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-u8EHKj8G8GQ/URqu55sM6yI/AAAAAAAAAbs/lIXX_GlTdmI/s160-c/Orange%252520Sunset.jpg",
    "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-74Z5qj4bTDE/URqu6LSrJrI/AAAAAAAAAbs/XzmVkw90szQ/s160-c/Orchid.jpg",
    "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-lEQE4h6TePE/URqu6t_lSkI/AAAAAAAAAbs/zvGYKOea_qY/s160-c/Over%252520there.jpg",
    "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-cauH-53JH2M/URqu66v_USI/AAAAAAAAAbs/EucwwqclfKQ/s160-c/Plumes.jpg",
    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-eDLT2jHDoy4/URqu7axzkAI/AAAAAAAAAbs/iVZE-xJ7lZs/s160-c/Rainbokeh.jpg"

};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Check it](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%3C?%3E%29)

```
List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(imageThumbUrlsRandom);
Collections.shuffle(arr);
arr.toArray(imageThumbUrlsRandom);
```

And if you have your own RNG (or if you just want to specify a seed for a default one), you can pass it:

```
long seed = 0xDEADBEEFL;
Random rng = new Random(seed);
List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(imageThumbUrlsRandom);
Collections.shuffle(arr, rng);
arr.toArray(imageThumbUrlsRandom);
```

Comment: Would it be possible for me to specify a number to shuffle my String Array by?

Comment: You mean to specify RNG? Seed for RNG?