# How to generate random number with different result

Tags: android, random

I am developing an application which involves a quiz.

I have used Randomly method for displaying question.

I wish to display these question in different values without repeating the same values.

I solved the problem thanks to your assistance.

Here is the code:

```
  final int[] solutionArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

  shuffleArray(solutionArray);

  currentQ = list_question.get(solutionArray[question_id]);
```

And

```
public void shuffleArray(int[] ar) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      int a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: The full projest is https://www.dropbox.com/sh/anxclyetysu3m9j/tUF_02XUg5

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code that you are having problems with here.

Comment: You should edit your Question and post your code there, preferably formatted.

Comment: The codes are update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create array (list) from your questions and suffle that array.

See this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20269756/2611927